# How to orderby child property in EF

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, left-join

I basically want to write this in Lambda EF.

```
select c.* from company c
left join companyfeature cf 
on c.companyID = cf.companyID
AND cf.FeatureID = 1
order by FeatureID desc, c.Name
```

I can't seem to figure it out.
*In EF they are Companies & CompanyFeatures entities*

**For Claus:**
I never said I didn't try, I said I couldn't figure it out. But to prove I'm not some free loader to you; here is my linq statement. (Yes I have my FK in place)

```
Companies
.OrderByDescending(c => c.CompanyFeatures.Any(f => f.FeatureID == 1))
.ThenBy(c => c.Name)
```

That actually works, but it produces an ungodly SQL statement that takes 6 seconds vs ms for my SQL statement above. So I assume I've wrote it incorrectly. I know there are a lot smarter people out there than me so I'm hoping someone will be willing to share their knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No reason to do joins, if you got proper foreign keys on your table layout. And such, just write it, and post your attempt if you still have problems, rather than ask people to write the entire solution for you, without even trying.

Comment: You only need to formulate the left outer join in LINQ.  Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: What use is ordering by FeatureID if you are already restricting FeatureID to one value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Note that this is C# but VB is quite similar.):

```
 var result = 
    from Company in Companies
    from CompanyFeature in Company.CompanyFeatures.Where(cf => cf.FeatureID == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby Company.Name
    select { Company, CompanyFeature };
```